# pgadmin > nginx > kubernetes (nginx) ingress (too many redirects)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, pgadmin, nginx-ingress

I have just successfully installed [pgadmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) app on Kubernetes but I am having troubles with ingress nginx.

I have an internal reversed proxy in front of `pgadmin` app to host it under a subdirectory. I am simply following [documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.30/container_deployment.html) to achieve that. The `nginx.conf` file looks like this:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes  1;
events {
  worker_connections  10240;
}
http {
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    location /pgadmin4/ {
      proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin4;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_pass http://pgadmin;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine, I can access the website with no problem if I directly access the node where the app runs on.

Now I want an ingress rule to have the app accessible on `http://mycompanydomain.com/pgadmin4`. The ingress server is a `kubernetes nginx` server which I don't administrate myself. And I would say this is where I am getting troubles with. My ingress rule is as simple as:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: pgadmin
  namespace: ...
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /pgadmin4
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: pgadmin-nginx
              servicePort: 80
```

Now I am left with a some redirect loop and the page cannot be served:

[image]

I have tried a whole combination of settings to no success and spent too much time on it and I am afraid I need a deeper knowledge on `nginx`.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem? I'm running into the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately not , I have spent a couple hours on it so please if you find something on it I appreciate it

Comment: I was able to get past this. While I wasn't using an nginx ingress controller I still had an initial nginx which proxied to an nginx running as a container in the pgadmin pod. Once I got rid of the nginx in the pod, and moved the nginx config to the first nginx the redirect loop completely went away. Now, if that doesn't work for you or you can't add the required annotations so that the controller is the only nginx, I was able to get further by adding `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`. This led to a CSRF error, but the redirects stopped. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am pretty sure I used those properties, just not sure at which proxy and what was the result . I would have to spend some extra time following new clues . But well , thanks for the hints and let us know if you get a good answer for the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the environment variable `SCRIPT_NAME=/pgadmin4` as described here
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/7.8/container_deployment.html#traefik

Answer (score 0):

For helm installation use context:- env.contextPath=/pgadmin4 during installation

helm install my-release runix/pgadmin4 -n myproject --set env.contextPath=/pgadmin4

add accordingly the changes in the ingress / istio virtual service file like below fir istio vs

```
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /pgadmin4
    - uri:
        prefix: /pgadmin4/
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-release-pgadmin4.myproject.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

tunnel if on remote (31367 is the node port of istio-ingressgateway svc https port)
ssh -L 8085:localhost:31367 user@1.2.3.4

now try accessing
https://localhost:8085/pgadmin4